# Values That Are Saved In The Respective Register After Executing

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

**QUESTION:** Fill the gaps with the values that are saved in the respective register after executing the respective line.
Enter all values in hexadecimal and in 32 bits.

**MY THINKING:** I'm new at Assembly. I know that values like EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, ESP, or EBP are for any 32-bit register.
Or the values like AX, BX, CX, or DX are for any 16-bit register.
I've read that xor eax, eax — set the contents of EAX to zero. That means that the first gap is 0x00000000, right?
Second gap copies the 0x12345678 into eax. That means eax = 0x12345678.
3rd gap should be 0x00000000 too, because 0 copies the value into ebx? And for other gaps I could not find anything.

```
xor eax, eax           ; eax = 0x00000000 (Gap 1)
mov eax, 0x12345678    ; eax = 0x12345678 (Gap 2)
mov ebx, 0
mov bx, ax             ; ebx = 0x00005678 (Gap 3)
mov bl, ah             ; ebx = 0x00005656 (Gap 4)
mov eax, 0xFFFFFFFF   
sar eax, 8             ; eax = 0xFFFFFFFF (Gap 5)
shr eax, 8             ; eax = 0x00000000 (Gap 6)
sar eax, 8             ; eax = 0x00000000 (Gap 7)
ror eax, 8             ; eax = 0x00000000 (Gap 8)
```

Comment: Yes, the first two results are correct. As for the rest remember that `ax` is not just a 16 bit register, it's specifically the low 16 bits of `eax`. That should cover the next two blanks. For the final four you should know what the instructions do, consult an instruction set reference. You can also run the code in a debugger to verify your values.

Comment: please fill in your answers first

Comment: Okay, I ll edit it in my question.

Comment: #4 is wrong, `bl` is the lowest byte.

Comment: Okay, now I think #4 ist correct.

Comment: The shr or sar instruction is used to shift the bits of the operand destination to the right, by the number of bits specified in the count operand.

So if we have
mov eax, 0xFFFFFFFF  
sar eax, 8

than eax for gap should be 0xFFFFFFFF, because it shifts the old bits to the right and place the new bits there which are 0xFFFFFFFF.

So for gap 6 we have another shift to the right, but I dont know what comes at the place of that gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov eax, 0x12345678    ; eax = 0x12345678 (Gap 2)
mov ebx, 0
mov bx, ax             ; ebx = 0x00005678 (Gap 3)
mov bl, ah             ; ebx = 0x00005656 (Gap 4)
mov eax, 0xFFFFFFFF   
sar eax, 8             ; eax = 0xFFFFFFFF (Gap 5)
shr eax, 8             ; eax = 0x00FFFFFF (Gap 6)
sar eax, 8             ; eax = 0x0000FFFF(Gap 7)
ror eax, 8             ; eax = 0xFF0000FF(Gap 8)
```

I think I got it.